# How can step through an Action that is requested from JavaScript during execution?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2008, iis-7, localhost

There is this one action that is requested using javascript during the loading of a page, it takes over 25 seconds to resolve. Looking at the code makes me think there is a scaling issue, but I am wondering if there is any way I can step through the code during the request so I can see what is happening. I try clicking 'debug/start debugging' but it won't launch the proper URL (access to the site is subdomain based), and it will also not find certain dependencies. I am able to browse the site directly via URL locally after mapping a URL via my hosts file to localhost (127...) but the default url that pops up (localhost...) from debug does not work because it is not formatted properly.

Any ideas?

Comment: so, you're saying that on your local computer it doesn't take 25 seconds to complete ?

Comment: nah it does, but I'm trying to see why in the code in real time, like some loop that takes a really long time for example

Comment: you could try logging to text file, or remote debugging

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can attach the debugger to your browser by selecting "Attach to process" under "Debug" menu.

Comment: it's not gonna help if the app is on a remote server, and you don't attach to the browser, you attach to the w3wp IIS process

Comment: "No symbols are loaded for any call stack frame. The source code cannot be displayed." when I click Pause, how to inspect?

Comment: @Omu - can't seem to find this process

Comment: @Ryan if the app is not hosted on your computer than there is no way you could find it

Comment: The app is most definitely hosted on my computer, just like my question states: "...in IIS locally after mapping a URL via my hosts file to localhost";

Answer (score 0):

In the past, at least with ASP.NET we have used [tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y13fw6we%28VS.71%29.aspx) to debug issues.  You will just need to enable it in the webconfig.  If you use warn, the messages will show in red and be easier to spot.